# Routes advertised via prefix list in BGP list

Tags: routing, vpn, bgp

I have advertised IP address 10.1.1.0/24 using IP-prefix list but it is not showing subnet mask in advertised route. Can you explain this behavior.

```
> show ip bgp vpnv4 all neighbors   10.27.0.21  advertised-routes
> 
>    Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
> Route Distinguisher: 22870:10 (default for vrf Data)
> *> 10.1.1.0     10.1.1.33            0         100 i

> Total number of prefixes 1
```

Comment: why do you think this a prblem ?

Comment: 10.1.1.144 not received at 10.27.0.21. that is directly connected

Comment: Provide BGP and prefix-list config please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found.  Becuase mask value wasn't defined in network command and also auto-summariztion enabled.
Network 10.1.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0
No  auto-summariztion

Comment: Glad you found it!  Please be sure to mark your own response as the answer.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.